# openssl CRC32 calculation

Tags: openssl, crc32

I have seen some of the other questions here about the CRC 32 calculation. But none were satisfactory for me, hence this.

Does openssl libraries have any api support for calculating the CRC32? I am already using openssl for SHA1, so would prefer to use it than link in one more library for CRC32(my implementation is in C).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, OpenSSL doesn't include CRC32 code.

However, `zlib` is a very common library which does. Try searching for "crc32" in http://www.zlib.net/manual.html

Comment: Thanks, that is an option. But I found cryptopp (http://www.cryptopp.com) useful.